# Angular Finalize Change Detection

Tags: rxjs, angular9

I have the following defined in my component's HTML:

```html
<button mat-button type="submit" [disabled]="invalidEmail" [ladda]="isLoading">Reset Password</button>
```

Where the `[ladda]` is a custom directive that shows a loading icon on the button when the respective variable is true; in this case the variable is named `isLoading`. Generally I'm doing this when hitting the server, so I will set `isLoading` to true before I hit the server and then set it to false when the response is returned.

Where this gets a little hairy is when I try to use an rxjs pipe/finalize pattern. If I run the following, the change is never detected:

```js
this.passwordService.resetPassword(input)
    .pipe(finalize(() => this.isLoading = false))
    .subscribe(
        () => this.success = true,
        err => this.error = JSON.stringify(err)
    );
```

I have to manually call NgZone::run in order for it to work:

```js
this.passwordService.resetPassword(input)
    .pipe(finalize(() => this.ngZone.run(() => this.isLoading = false)))
    .subscribe(
        () => this.success = true,
        err => this.error = JSON.stringify(err)
    );
```

Why is this, am I doing this wrong?

**update** - per request, here is the resetPassword method:

```js
resetPassword(reset: IPasswordReset): Observable<void> {
    const url = `${environment.ApiUrl}/Api/UserProfile/ResetPasswordFromToken`;
    const options = new HttpOptions();
    options.headers = new HttpHeaders();
    options.headers = options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this.http.post(url, reset, null, options);
}
```

Comment: Can you share your Directive

Comment: @RafiHenig - I am using the ladda directive from this example: https://medium.com/coyo-tech/how-to-add-a-loading-state-to-angular-material-buttons-f0c3272e49a

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u2efyq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts it works here with a simple observable created with setTimeout. I don't know what causes your observable to be run out of zone.

Comment: You are going to need to show the code for the resetPassword method, it is the completion of the observable that method returns that is running out of zone. It has nothing to do with the ladda directive, the fact it works when you set isLoading in zone means the directive is working as expected.

Comment: I can't see any reason why that would run out of zone

Comment: @AdrianBrand - do you think that I should submit a bug report?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @mostafa8026 - No, in the end I just kept calling ngZone's run method.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't succeed to find an explanation why code is running outside the ngZone while using `finalize` rxjs operator, maybe it's an issue with it.
Until we find an explanation you can use one of these solutions:

```
this.passwordService.resetPassword(input)
   .pipe(
     finalize(() => {
       this.isLoading = false;
       this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); // <-- add this line to your code
     }
   ))
   .subscribe(...);
```

Otherwise you need to handle that inside the subscribe callbacks

```
this.passwordService.resetPassword(input)
  .pipe(
    ...
  ).
  subscribe({
    next: () => {...},
    error: () => {...},
    complete: () => {
      this.isLoading = false;
    } 
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the complete method?

```
this.passwordService.resetPassword(input)
    .subscribe(
        () => this.success = true,
        err => this.error = JSON.stringify(err),
        () => this.isLoading = false
    );
```

Comment: The coding paradigm I have to follow uses the rxjs pipe/finalize pattern (this is for work), but I did try that as well and the same thing happens in that the change detection never occurs so the ladda keeps spinning.